# Redirect xsession from VNC to physical screen

Tags: vnc, gentoo, x-server

We all know that it is possible to run a VNC server in an xsession to remotely view/control this session.
What I like to know is the following: Is it possible to display the xsession that was started with VNC (via xinetd) on a real hardware screen?

The background is: I have a HTPC that is attached to the network via GLan and to a beamer via DVI as well as to sound. What I would like to do is: Login on the server from my desktop, start a movie on the server and watch it on the beamer.

Maybe it is just enough to start the vnc server while booting but I don't know if this has some issues. Also I would like to start this vnc server only on demand (so via xinetd).

So did anyone of you try this?
I would appriciate any advice (even how to do it without VNC, but still over the net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found something out.
For my problem: I circumvented it by using x11vnc and connecting it to the hardware display, so I could control it via vnc remotely.

As to the problem of transferring the sessions: It seems this is not possible (though I am not the best source for this) but someone told me about using a x server proxy that enables the user to pass applications between two servers that run on this proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use [xbmc](http://xbmc.org/download/) instead a vnc server? (it's the proper way to stream video from a htpc)

Anyway... you could use [thinstation](http://www.thinstation.org/) to connect to the vnc server (i'm wrong here because you want to connect to the htpc)

In the official wiki of gentoo you've a guide with the complete [configuration of X11VNC](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/X11VNC) and how-to make the tunneling with ssh.

good luck!

Comment: I did not know of them and I also don't know if they are suitable for my needs as my server is more than just a HTPC.

Comment: I think you must see what xbmc offers to you and then enjoy your music and videos in a better way.